How to create an AVD for a flip phone with a small cover screen?
Android 15 adds Cover screen support:

Your app can declare a property that Android 15 uses to allow your Application or Activity to be presented on the small cover screens of supported flippable devices. These screens are too small to be considered as compatible targets for Android apps to run on, but your app can opt in to supporting them, making your app available in more places.

Declare the property like this:
<application>
   <property
     android:name="android.window.PROPERTY_ACTIVITY_EMBEDDING_ALLOW_SYSTEM_OVERRIDE"
     android:value="true|false"/>
 </application>

Q. How to create emulator AVDs for testing flippable devices?
There's a device definition for a Resizable folding phone/tablet. But that one folds out horizontally from a phone to a tablet. To test the Cover Screen feature we need a phone that folds in vertically (like a RAZR) to reveal a small cover screen, "too small to be considered as compatible targets for Android apps".
I tried various things including searching for a Flip phone "hardware profile", downloading a Samsung Galaxy Z Flip 6 skin, and creating a hardware profile from the Resizable folding phone/tablet hardware profile using the unfolded screen dimensions of the Galaxy Z Flip 6. (That last approach produces AVDs that go into a boot loop with lots of errors in the logcat.) I also tried asking Gemini in Android Studio for answers. None of this worked.
